# Creating a simple wcf service publishing it to my webhotel, and get it to work

Tags: wcf

This seems to be a recurring problem to me. I want to get started doing wcf services. I create a new Wcf Service Library, compile it, and publish it using FTP to my providers webhotel. But its not working. I somehow cant get access. I dont want some fancy security model - i just want to get a hole through to my simple webservice. Seems that its the part when i publish it to my webhotel (in a subdomain) that breaks the webservice - its working perfectly when starting it locally.

How to proceed anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a bit about my findings, this solved my issue: http://www.vikingworks.dk/post/WCF-Service-on-hosted-environment.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Often you need confguration information to host a service. If the service is hosted in IIS, then you need that configuration in web.config.  Are you updating Web.config properly?    Some hosters don't allow it.

To address this problem you can [set up your IIS-hosted WCF service to read its config data from elsewhere](http://blogs.msdn.com/dotnetinterop/archive/2008/09/22/custom-service-config-file-for-a-wcf-service-hosted-in-iis.aspx).